# NetBSD sh -c "echo OK" doesn't give any output?

Tags: shell, netbsd

I'm testing the portability of some stuff I'm writing to BSD. It's working on Linux, FreeBSD, OpenBSD. It isn't working on NetBSD.

The following is on a fresh VM installation I've made just for the purpose of testing this. I've traced the issue to

```
NetBSD$ uname -a
NetBSD NetBSD.local 9.1 NetBSD 9.1 (GENERIC) #0: Sun Oct 18 19:24:30 UTC 2020 mkrepro@mkrepro.NetBSD.org:/usr/src/sys/arch/amd64/compile/GENERIC amd64
```

```
NetBSD$ cat /etc/shells                                                                                 
#       $NetBSD: shells,v 1.3 1996/12/29 03:23:07 mrg Exp $
#
# List of acceptable shells for chpass(1).
# Ftpd will not allow users to connect who are not using
# one of these shells.

/bin/sh
/bin/csh
/bin/ksh
/usr/pkg/bin/zsh
/usr/pkg/bin/bash
```

```
NetBSD$ for s in /bin/sh /bin/csh /bin/ksh /usr/pkg/bin/zsh /usr/pkg/bin/bash ; do echo $s; $s -c "echo OK" ; done
/bin/sh
/bin/csh
OK
/bin/ksh
/usr/pkg/bin/zsh
OK
/usr/pkg/bin/bash
OK
NetBSD$ su -
Password:
NetBSD# for s in /bin/sh /bin/csh /bin/ksh /usr/pkg/bin/zsh /usr/pkg/bin/bash ; do echo $s; $s -c "echo OK" ; done
/bin/sh
OK
/bin/csh
OK
/bin/ksh
OK
/usr/pkg/bin/zsh
OK
/usr/pkg/bin/bash
OK
```

Why doesn't `sh -c "echo OK"` and `ksh -c "echo OK"` work when I'm a non-root user, and why do they work when I'm root?

Other shells (`csh`, `zsh`, `bash`) work correctly, as shown above.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on an identical setup. Does `sh -c "echo OK"` not print anything if you give that command by itself, or is it only when it's part of your loop?

Comment: Do you have `SHA1 (/bin/sh) = f3d8c4ba3aec3baefa2e5758e628694afc190b85`
and `SHA1 (/bin/ksh) = b0835284c64fefceac9d96b34e8a482473716ec5`? (use the `sha1` command on the shell executables).

Comment: @Kusalananda, thanks for the hashes and confirmation it worked for you. That pushed me to second guess my assumptions and I found the issue.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer but since this comes down to a change you had made to your system, I am closing this as not reproducible because it is unlikely to help future users.

Answer (score 0):

As Kusalananda's hashes matched mine and they hadn't the issue I dug further in my setup. My dotfiles are common between the OS variants and I don't have the issue there, but NetBSD sh and ksh behaves differently than other shells I've access and the issue was in my dotfiles.

I'm defining ENV so that I can define useful functions for interactive shells. I'm calling `exit` if the shell isn't interactive, I don't remember why as non csh shells don't source anything when non interactive. Well not all of them: NetBSD's sh and ksh are. And not only they are the only Bourne shell I've tested with that behaviour, they are also the only one which exit the shell on that `exit`, the other shells (tested with `-ic`) just stop processing the file and execute the command passed to `-c`.

Comment: You're definitely not using `ENV` in a Ksh or POSIX compatible way!  The `exit` command terminates the shell -- you just want to avoid sourcing the contents of your script, and the recommended way to do that is to wrap the contents in a conditional `if` statement with a test for when you want to evaluate the content.  There's a fancier way to avoid the ENV file for true Ksh (and compatible), but it has some potential security risks.